# Coursera Scala SBT submission issues

Tags: scala, functional-programming, sbt, typesafe, reactive

I am a current student at the EPFL functional programming in SCALA course on coursera.
I have successfully passed the first course by submitting my assignments via sbt with no issues until now.

When I tried to submit the 'calculator' assignment with my generated token, I get error messages like

> Set current project to src (in build
>   file:/C:/Users/user/Desktop/cousera%20class/calculator/calculator/src/)
>
> > submit [error] Not a valid command: submit (similar: set) [error] Not a valid project ID: submit [error] Expected ':' (if selecting a
> >     configuration) [error] Not a valid key: submit [error] submit

Please who's faced this challenge in the past? I need help

Comment: we need to see the commands you are running

Comment: Ask the  Coursera support people on thesite for this course, much more likely to know.

Comment: it looks like you are running it from the wrong directory, not from project root

Comment: sbt submit ***********@gmail.com   fgfhYIjgxjdkf  @yǝsʞǝlA

Comment: I don't remember how they did it. I think you either have to add their sbt plugin to your project or globally to make submit task available. seems like you are missing that. They might provide their own sbt version - don't remember.

Comment: ok thanks guys. i finally found my way around it. It was just a directory issue...

Comment: I have the same problem but I am at the right directory. Do I need any specific `sbt` version?

Comment: It does not seem to be solved at the time of writing my comment, you may ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have done.

- Ignored all the setup tutorials that are there.
- Installed `sbt` on my Ubuntu using `apt`.
- Imported the example project [here](https://www.coursera.org/learn/scala-functional-programming/programming/EoeMo/example).
- Went into following the steps there.
- Submitted using `sbt` then `submit myemail@email.com [token]`.

Hope that can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this helps anybody else, I had the same problem.  I tried running

```
sbt submit {my.email@domain.com} {token}
```

from the project root, but that didn't work.  Running sbt by itself entered an interpreter type thing, which accepts commands, and running

```
submit {my.email@domain.com} {token}
```

from there worked.

Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely running `sbt` in the wrong directory.

Make sure you are running `sbt` command in the directory that contains the source code (src/), and build file (build.sbt). Then, run the submit command:

```
submit <my.email@domain.com> <token>
```